# Monitoring SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, monitoring, governance

This one isn't something that's not working per se, just looking for some ideas/feedback from my SharePoint comrades.

When I was still mostly supporting on-prem farms (oh the days!) I bashed together a little monitoring site inside SP that used some timer job-fired scripts to populate lists with system info - database size and state, content source crawls, timer jobs, etc - then fired workflows/alerts based on those items (one example was if a database was over 100GB it triggered as this is over best practice size).

So my question is: **what kind of items like this would be of use for monitoring in SharePoint Online?**

Obviously databases, search topology, content sources and timer jobs are out as MS control those now, but I can think of a few things that could be monitored in this way (i.e. with a script grabbing the info and putting it in SP, just using CSOM rather than SSOM):

- Lists approaching the view threshold
- Quota usage
- Site and page requests
- Workflow usage
- External sharing

I know the idea is most of this should be managed from the Admin Portal (especially things that fall under the S&C Center) but the idea I had around this was to decouple the admin and power user parts by making some information available as 'regular' data for power user and governance officer types (I could see something like this maybe being a good tool for enforcing informational hygiene and governance policies).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see why this has been put on hold. It is a specific problem, i.e. 'what would be considered of value to monitor in SharePoint Online'.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your list

- Lists approaching the view threshold
- Quota usage
- Site and page requests
- Workflow usage
- External sharing

I would add

- Lists unchanged in x months
- Possibly expose the site owners/SC Admins

Other than that, I think you have a good range there!

Comment: The lists/sites unchanged one is a good idea, that would be useful for stopping site sprawl etc.

Comment: Also helps with stale content.

Comment: I hadn't heard that term before but it sounds suitably buzzword-y to now be part of my spiel on why clients should pay us a ton of money to design governance frameworks!